# Android animation inside AnimatorSet

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

So, my coworkers have been doing this app for very long time and we have a method that animates buying drink to the cart. Now, animation that we have right now is just linear falling with some bounce effect. Since the whole logic is linked to listeners and interfaces, in order to preserve that, I want to impmlement ArcTranslation to it. Now, my ArcTranslation.class looks like:

```
 import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

/**
 * Created by vulov on 16-May-16.\n
 */
public class ArcTranslation extends Animation {

    private Point start;
    private Point end;
    private Point middle;
    private final float mFromXValue;
    private final float mToXValue;
    private final float mYValue;
    private final int mFromXType;
    private final int mToXType;
    private final int mYType;

    /**
     * A translation along an arc defined by three points and a Bezier Curve
     *
     * @param duration   - the time in ms it will take for the translation to complete
     * @param fromXType  - One of Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, or Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT.
     * @param fromXValue - Change in X coordinate to apply at the start of the animation
     * @param toXType    - One of Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, or Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT.
     * @param toXValue   - Change in X coordinate to apply at the end of the animation
     * @param yType      - One of Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, or Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT.
     * @param yValue     - Change in Y coordinate to apply at the middle of the animation (the radius of the arc)
     */
    public ArcTranslation(long duration, int fromXType, float fromXValue,
                          int toXType, float toXValue, int yType, float yValue) {
        setDuration(duration);

        mFromXValue = fromXValue;
        mToXValue = toXValue;
        mYValue = yValue;

        mFromXType = fromXType;
        mToXType = toXType;
        mYType = yType;

    }

    /**
     * Calculate the position on a quadratic bezier curve given three points
     * and the percentage of time passed.
     * from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve
     *
     * @param interpolatedTime - the fraction of the duration that has passed where 0<=time<=1
     * @param p0               - a single dimension of the starting point
     * @param p1               - a single dimension of the middle point
     * @param p2               - a single dimension of the ending point
     */
    private long calcBezier(float interpolatedTime, float p0, float p1, float p2) {
        return Math.round((Math.pow((1 - interpolatedTime), 2) * p0)
                + (2 * (1 - interpolatedTime) * interpolatedTime * p1)
                + (Math.pow(interpolatedTime, 2) * p2));
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        float dx = calcBezier(interpolatedTime, start.x, middle.x, end.x);
        float dy = calcBezier(interpolatedTime, start.y, middle.y, end.y);

        t.getMatrix().setTranslate(dx, dy);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
        int startX = Math.round(resolveSize(mFromXType, mFromXValue, width, parentWidth));
        int endX = Math.round(resolveSize(mToXType, mToXValue, width, parentWidth));
        int middleY = Math.round(resolveSize(mYType, mYValue, width, parentWidth));
        int middleX = startX + ((endX - startX) / 2);
        start = new Point(startX, 0);
        end = new Point(endX, 0);
        middle = new Point(middleX, middleY);
    }
}
```

And the method that animates drinks in the cart:

```
private void animateToCart(int[] location, final Drink drink) {
        final TextView badge = new TextView(getActivity());
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.MenuGridBothPaddings), getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen
                .MenuGridBothPaddings));
        params.setMargins(width + (width / 2) - 10, location[1] - getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.ActionBarHeight), 0, 0);
        badge.setLayoutParams(params);

        badge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        badge.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bottom_menu_badge));
        badge.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        badge.setText("1");
        badge.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        badge.bringToFront();
        top.addView(badge, params);
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSetList.add(animatorSet);
        CancelListener cancelListener = new CancelListener(badge, drink);
        animatorSet.addListener(cancelListener);
       /* animatorSet.addListener(new SimpleAnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animator);
                badge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                restoreOrdersBadgeAnimate();
                if (Session.isOrderStatusSuccess()) {
                    Session.clearTab();
                }
                if (Session.getReceiverUser() != null && Session.getNumBarTabDrinks() >= 1) {
                    setActiveDialog(displayError(R.string.MenuOneAtATime));
                    return;
                }
                if (DrinkCategoryMetadata.isMixerDrinkCategory(drink.categoryId)) {
                    DrinkMeta drinkMeta = Session.addBarTabDrinkGetMeta(drink);
                    Dialog dialog = new MixersDialog(getActivity(), drink);
                    dialog.setOnDismissListener(new MixersDismissListener(drink, drinkMeta));
                    dialog.show();
                    setActiveDialog(dialog);
                } else {
                    Session.addBarTabDrink(drink);
                    ((BmadUserActivity) getActivity()).setBarTabNum(Session.getNumBarTabDrinks(), true);
                    setBarTabNum(Session.getNumBarTabDrinks());
                    if (ApplicationLoader.getCurrentFragment() instanceof BuyDrinksFragment) {
                        ((BmadUserActivity) getActivity()).getBottomMenu().getBadge(BottomMenu.Item.CURRENT).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//change from INVISIBLE to VISIBLE
                    }
                    ((BmadUserActivity) getActivity()).setTooltipBarTab(drink.name);
                    setTooltipBarTab(drink.name);
                }
            }
        });*/
        animatorSet.playTogether(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(badge, "translationY", (height - location[1]) - getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.BottomMenuHeight) - 80));
        animatorSet.setDuration(height / 2);
        animatorSet.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
        animatorSet.start();
    }
```

The things I want to do here:
- How to implement my animation class into this flow of events(into AnimatorSet)
- Since this is a fragment inside activity with tab layout at the bottom, how to make view that is dropping to be in front of everything, so when it reaches bottom it isn't behind tab bar?